# Searching for strings in random data

Tags: algorithm, search, text, statistics

Is there any standard search algorithm for human-readable text strings in a random binary file?

For example processing of an executable file should return list of some function names from import table and string constants.

It's obviously must utilize set of language-specific dictionaries and be based on statistical theory.

Comment: (1) In executeable files, there is no trace to the function names usually, they are part of the source code. (2) You can represent anything you want with binary code, use k bits for a character, give each character a unique encoding of length k, and repeat to get the string. Not sure what you are asking..

Comment: Of course I supposed byte arrays corresponding to the strings in existing standard character encoding.

Comment: The solutions I know are much simpler: just emit sequences of ASCII characters (i.e. byte values 0x20 - 0x7e) of a certain minimum length.

Comment: @Henry It would return too much trash as not really text bytes can be in ASCII diapason and also it doesn't consider another encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Hidden Markov model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_markov_model). For both the binary and the text data, you create a model that describes how likely any byte is given the preceding or a few preceding bytes. Given also the probability of switching from one model to the other, the [Viterbi algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm) can find the most likely underlying alternation of binary and text.